# Qt cpp - Clean way to write QString into text file

Tags: c++, qt, iostream, qstring

I need to find a clean and fast way to write a `QString` in `.csv` file.
I tried:

```
QString path= QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + QString("/myfile.csv");
QFile file(path);
QString mystring = "Hello, world!";    
if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
        file.close();
    } else {
        QTextStream out(&file); out << mystring;
        file.close();
    }
```

But it writes for me `"???????"` in `myfile.csv`

Comment: file.write(mystring.toUtf8());

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Are you sure you use ASCII characters only, like in your example "Hello, world!"?

Comment: @vahancho yes, but with first comment it works!

Comment: @AndreySemenov if you write your comment as answer I will point it as solution :-)

Comment: @Elena Naah Scheff wrote very good answer))

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As Andrey didn't react yet, I will step in and provide some background about OPs issue:

From Qt doc. about [`QString`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#details):

> The [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) class provides a Unicode character string.
>
> [QString](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html) stores a string of 16-bit [QChar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html)s, where each [QChar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html) corresponds one Unicode 4.0 character. (Unicode characters with code values above 65535 are stored using surrogate pairs, i.e., two consecutive [QChar](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html)s.)

From Qt doc. about [`QTextStream::operator<<(const QString &string)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#operator-lt-lt-12):

> Writes the string *string* to the stream, and returns a reference to the [QTextStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html). The string is first encoded using the assigned codec (the default codec is [QTextCodec::codecForLocale()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html#codecForLocale)) before it is written to the stream.

and about [`QTextStream`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html) in general:

> Internally, [QTextStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html) uses a Unicode based buffer, and [QTextCodec](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html) is used by QTextStream to automatically support different character sets. By default, [QTextCodec::codecForLocale()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextcodec.html#codecForLocale) is used for reading and writing, but you can also set the codec by calling [setCodec()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setCodec). Automatic Unicode detection is also supported. When this feature is enabled (the default behavior), [QTextStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html) will detect the UTF-16 or the UTF-32 BOM (Byte Order Mark) and switch to the appropriate UTF codec when reading. [QTextStream](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html) does not write a BOM by default, but you can enable this by calling [setGenerateByteOrderMark](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setGenerateByteOrderMark)(true).

So, `"???????"` is probably `Hello, World!` encoded in [UTF-16](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16) or [UTF-32](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-32) where OPs view tool (which did output `"???????"`) was not able to detect this or even does not support this encoding.

The hint of [Andrey Semenov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3013108/andrey-semenov), to do instead:

```
file.write(mystring.toUtf8());
```

converts the `QString` contents to [UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) which

- consists of bytes
- is identical with [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) concerning the first 127 [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) characters.

[`QString::toUtf8()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstring.html#toUtf8) returns [`QByteArray`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html); and [`QTextStream::operator<<(const QByteArray&)`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#operator-lt-lt-15) very probably writes these bytes unchanged. (This even isn't mentioned in the doc.)

So, `Hello, World!` consists only of characters available in the ASCII table (with codes < 127). Even, if OPs view tool supports/expects e.g. [Windows 1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) it will not notice this. (I assume that a tool that cannot detect/process UTF-16 or UTF-32, probably cannot detect/process UTF-8 as well.)

---

Btw. to find out what encoding `"???????"` actually was, `myfile.csv` could be viewed with a hex-view tool. As the input is known, the encoding can probably be deduced from the output. (E.g. a `He` is `0x48 0x65` in ASCII *and* UTF-8, but `0x48 0x00 0x65 0x00` in UTF-16LE and `0x00 0x48 0x00 0x65` in UTF-16BE.)

---

I tried to reproduce the issue with an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

`testQTextStreamEncoding.cc`:

```
#include <QtWidgets>

int main(int, char**)
{
  const QString qString = "Hello, World!";
  const QString qPath("testQTextStreamEncoding.txt");
  QFile qFile(qPath);
  if (qFile.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)) {
    QTextStream out(&qFile); out << qString;
    qFile.close();
  }
  return 0;
}
```

and `testQTextStreamEncoding.pro`:

```
SOURCES = testQTextStreamEncoding.cc

QT += widgets
```

On [**cygwin**](http://www.cygwin.org), I did:

```
$ qmake-qt5

$ make
g++ -c -fno-keep-inline-dllexport -D_GNU_SOURCE -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -I. -isystem /usr/include/qt5 -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtWidgets -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtGui -isystem /usr/include/qt5/QtCore -I. -I/usr/lib/qt5/mkspecs/cygwin-g++ -o testQTextStreamEncoding.o testQTextStreamEncoding.cc
g++  -o testQTextStreamEncoding.exe testQTextStreamEncoding.o   -lQt5Widgets -lQt5Gui -lQt5Core -lGL -lpthread 

$ ./testQTextStreamEncoding

$ hexdump.exe -C testQTextStreamEncoding.txt
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 57  6f 72 6c 64 21           |Hello, World!|
0000000d

$
```

So, it seems I cannot reproduce on my side what OP described.
I also tried it with the code compiled and ran in VS2013:

```
$ rm testQTextStreamEncoding.txt ; ls testQTextStreamEncoding.txt
ls: cannot access 'testQTextStreamEncoding.txt': No such file or directory
```

(Compile, Run in VS2013)

```
$ hexdump.exe -C testQTextStreamEncoding.txt
00000000  48 65 6c 6c 6f 2c 20 57  6f 72 6c 64 21           |Hello, World!|
0000000d

$
```

Again, I cannot reproduce. It would be interesting to see how the OP produced `"???????"` and what it actually contained.